# Unable to display CUDA C results

Tags: c, bitmap, cuda

I am studying a CUDA C example (ripple.cu in chapter 5) on the *CUDA C by Example* book; when I compile the file it seems there is no problem; here's what i type on the terminal:

```
 nvcc ripple.cu -lGL -lGLU -lX11 -lXi -lXmu -lglut -lGLEW
```

When I run the executable i should get an image like this:

[image]

However this is what i get instead:

[image]

Here I post the file *ripple.cu*  and the related header files:

```
// ripple.cu
#include "cuda.h"
#include "../common/book.h"
#include "../common/cpu_anim.h"

#define DIM 1024
#define PI 3.1415926535897932f

__global__ void kernel( unsigned char *ptr, int ticks ) {
// map from threadIdx/BlockIdx to pixel position
int x = threadIdx.x + blockIdx.x * blockDim.x;
int y = threadIdx.y + blockIdx.y * blockDim.y;
int offset = x + y * blockDim.x * gridDim.x;

// now calculate the value at that position
float fx = x - DIM/2;
float fy = y - DIM/2;
float d = sqrtf( fx * fx + fy * fy );
unsigned char grey = (unsigned char)(128.0f + 127.0f *
                                     cos(d/10.0f - ticks/7.0f) /
                                     (d/10.0f + 1.0f));    
ptr[offset*4 + 0] = grey;
ptr[offset*4 + 1] = grey;
ptr[offset*4 + 2] = grey;
ptr[offset*4 + 3] = 255;
}

struct DataBlock {
unsigned char   *dev_bitmap;
CPUAnimBitmap  *bitmap;
};

void generate_frame( DataBlock *d, int ticks ) {
dim3    blocks(DIM/16,DIM/16);
dim3    threads(16,16);
kernel<<<blocks,threads>>>( d->dev_bitmap, ticks );

HANDLE_ERROR( cudaMemcpy( d->bitmap->get_ptr(),
                          d->dev_bitmap,
                          d->bitmap->image_size(),
                          cudaMemcpyDeviceToHost ) );
}

// clean up memory allocated on the GPU
void cleanup( DataBlock *d ) {
HANDLE_ERROR( cudaFree( d->dev_bitmap ) ); 
}

int main( void ) {
DataBlock   data;
CPUAnimBitmap  bitmap( DIM, DIM, &data );
data.bitmap = &bitmap;

HANDLE_ERROR( cudaMalloc( (void**)&data.dev_bitmap,
                          bitmap.image_size() ) );

bitmap.anim_and_exit( (void (*)(void*,int))generate_frame,
                        (void (*)(void*))cleanup );
}
```

Now i post the *headers* which are contained into a folder named *common*:

```
// book.h
#ifndef __BOOK_H__
#define __BOOK_H__
#include <stdio.h>

static void HandleError( cudaError_t err,
                     const char *file,
                     int line ) {
if (err != cudaSuccess) {
    printf( "%s in %s at line %d\n", cudaGetErrorString( err ),
            file, line );
    exit( EXIT_FAILURE );
}
}
#define HANDLE_ERROR( err ) (HandleError( err, __FILE__, __LINE__ ))


#define HANDLE_NULL( a ) {if (a == NULL) { \
                        printf( "Host memory failed in %s at line %d\n", \
                                __FILE__, __LINE__ ); \
                        exit( EXIT_FAILURE );}}

template< typename T >
void swap( T& a, T& b ) {
T t = a;
a = b;
b = t;
}


void* big_random_block( int size ) {
unsigned char *data = (unsigned char*)malloc( size );
HANDLE_NULL( data );
for (int i=0; i<size; i++)
    data[i] = rand();

return data;
}

int* big_random_block_int( int size ) {
int *data = (int*)malloc( size * sizeof(int) );
HANDLE_NULL( data );
for (int i=0; i<size; i++)
    data[i] = rand();

return data;
}


// a place for common kernels - starts here

__device__ unsigned char value( float n1, float n2, int hue ) {
if (hue > 360)      hue -= 360;
else if (hue < 0)   hue += 360;

if (hue < 60)
    return (unsigned char)(255 * (n1 + (n2-n1)*hue/60));
if (hue < 180)
    return (unsigned char)(255 * n2);
if (hue < 240)
    return (unsigned char)(255 * (n1 + (n2-n1)*(240-hue)/60));
return (unsigned char)(255 * n1);
}

__global__ void float_to_color( unsigned char *optr,
                          const float *outSrc ) {
// map from threadIdx/BlockIdx to pixel position
int x = threadIdx.x + blockIdx.x * blockDim.x;
int y = threadIdx.y + blockIdx.y * blockDim.y;
int offset = x + y * blockDim.x * gridDim.x;

float l = outSrc[offset];
float s = 1;
int h = (180 + (int)(360.0f * outSrc[offset])) % 360;
float m1, m2;

if (l <= 0.5f)
    m2 = l * (1 + s);
else
    m2 = l + s - l * s;
m1 = 2 * l - m2;

optr[offset*4 + 0] = value( m1, m2, h+120 );
optr[offset*4 + 1] = value( m1, m2, h );
optr[offset*4 + 2] = value( m1, m2, h -120 );
optr[offset*4 + 3] = 255;
}

__global__ void float_to_color( uchar4 *optr,
                          const float *outSrc ) {
// map from threadIdx/BlockIdx to pixel position
int x = threadIdx.x + blockIdx.x * blockDim.x;
int y = threadIdx.y + blockIdx.y * blockDim.y;
int offset = x + y * blockDim.x * gridDim.x;

float l = outSrc[offset];
float s = 1;
int h = (180 + (int)(360.0f * outSrc[offset])) % 360;
float m1, m2;

if (l <= 0.5f)
    m2 = l * (1 + s);
else
    m2 = l + s - l * s;
m1 = 2 * l - m2;

optr[offset].x = value( m1, m2, h+120 );
optr[offset].y = value( m1, m2, h );
optr[offset].z = value( m1, m2, h -120 );
optr[offset].w = 255;
}


#if _WIN32
//Windows threads.
#include <windows.h>

typedef HANDLE CUTThread;
typedef unsigned (WINAPI *CUT_THREADROUTINE)(void *);

#define CUT_THREADPROC unsigned WINAPI
#define  CUT_THREADEND return 0

#else
//POSIX threads.
#include <pthread.h>

typedef pthread_t CUTThread;
typedef void *(*CUT_THREADROUTINE)(void *);

#define CUT_THREADPROC void
#define  CUT_THREADEND
#endif

//Create thread.
CUTThread start_thread( CUT_THREADROUTINE, void *data );

//Wait for thread to finish.
void end_thread( CUTThread thread );

//Destroy thread.
void destroy_thread( CUTThread thread );

//Wait for multiple threads.
void wait_for_threads( const CUTThread *threads, int num );

#if _WIN32
//Create thread
CUTThread start_thread(CUT_THREADROUTINE func, void *data){
    return CreateThread(NULL, 0, (LPTHREAD_START_ROUTINE)func, data, 0, NULL);
}

//Wait for thread to finish
void end_thread(CUTThread thread){
    WaitForSingleObject(thread, INFINITE);
    CloseHandle(thread);
}

//Destroy thread
void destroy_thread( CUTThread thread ){
    TerminateThread(thread, 0);
    CloseHandle(thread);
}

//Wait for multiple threads
void wait_for_threads(const CUTThread * threads, int num){
    WaitForMultipleObjects(num, threads, true, INFINITE);

    for(int i = 0; i < num; i++)
        CloseHandle(threads[i]);
}

#else
//Create thread
CUTThread start_thread(CUT_THREADROUTINE func, void * data){
    pthread_t thread;
    pthread_create(&thread, NULL, func, data);
    return thread;
}

//Wait for thread to finish
void end_thread(CUTThread thread){
    pthread_join(thread, NULL);
}

//Destroy thread
void destroy_thread( CUTThread thread ){
    pthread_cancel(thread);
}

//Wait for multiple threads
void wait_for_threads(const CUTThread * threads, int num){
    for(int i = 0; i < num; i++)
        end_thread( threads[i] );
}

#endif


// cpu_anim.h
#endif  // __BOOK_H__
```

Here's the second header:

```
// cpu_anim.h
#ifndef __CPU_ANIM_H__
#define __CPU_ANIM_H__

#include "gl_helper.h" 

#include <iostream>


struct CPUAnimBitmap {
unsigned char    *pixels;
int     width, height;
void    *dataBlock;
void (*fAnim)(void*,int);
void (*animExit)(void*);
void (*clickDrag)(void*,int,int,int,int);
int     dragStartX, dragStartY;

CPUAnimBitmap( int w, int h, void *d = NULL ) {
    width = w;
    height = h;
    pixels = new unsigned char[width * height * 4];
    dataBlock = d;
    clickDrag = NULL;
}

~CPUAnimBitmap() {
    delete [] pixels;
}

unsigned char* get_ptr( void ) const   { return pixels; }
long image_size( void ) const { return width * height * 4; }

void click_drag( void (*f)(void*,int,int,int,int)) {
    clickDrag = f;
}

void anim_and_exit( void (*f)(void*,int), void(*e)(void*) ) {
    CPUAnimBitmap**   bitmap = get_bitmap_ptr();
    *bitmap = this;
    fAnim = f;
    animExit = e;
    // a bug in the Windows GLUT implementation prevents us from
    // passing zero arguments to glutInit()
    int c=1;
    char* dummy = (char *)(void *)"";
    glutInit( &c, &dummy );
    glutInitDisplayMode( GLUT_DOUBLE | GLUT_RGBA );
    glutInitWindowSize( width, height );
    glutCreateWindow( "bitmap" );
    glutKeyboardFunc(Key);
    glutDisplayFunc(Draw);
    if (clickDrag != NULL)
        glutMouseFunc( mouse_func );
    glutIdleFunc( idle_func );
    glutMainLoop();
}

// static method used for glut callbacks
static CPUAnimBitmap** get_bitmap_ptr( void ) {
    static CPUAnimBitmap*   gBitmap;
    return &gBitmap;
}

// static method used for glut callbacks
static void mouse_func( int button, int state,
                        int mx, int my ) {
    if (button == GLUT_LEFT_BUTTON) {
        CPUAnimBitmap*   bitmap = *(get_bitmap_ptr());
        if (state == GLUT_DOWN) {
            bitmap->dragStartX = mx;
            bitmap->dragStartY = my;
        } else if (state == GLUT_UP) {
            bitmap->clickDrag( bitmap->dataBlock,
                               bitmap->dragStartX,
                               bitmap->dragStartY,
                               mx, my );
        }
    }
}

// static method used for glut callbacks
static void idle_func( void ) {
    static int ticks = 1;
    CPUAnimBitmap*   bitmap = *(get_bitmap_ptr());
    bitmap->fAnim( bitmap->dataBlock, ticks++ );
    glutPostRedisplay();
}

// static method used for glut callbacks
static void Key(unsigned char key, int x, int y) {
    switch (key) {
        case 27:
            CPUAnimBitmap*   bitmap = *(get_bitmap_ptr());
            bitmap->animExit( bitmap->dataBlock );
            //delete bitmap;
            exit(0);
    }
}

// static method used for glut callbacks
static void Draw( void ) {
    CPUAnimBitmap*   bitmap = *(get_bitmap_ptr());
    glClearColor( 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0 );
    glClear( GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT );
    glDrawPixels( bitmap->width, bitmap->height, GL_RGBA, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, bitmap->pixels );
    glutSwapBuffers();
}
};


#endif  // __CPU_ANIM_H__
```

I don't really know where the problem might be... I have already asked in the NVIDA FORUM without success... Here's the link where you can download the source code in case you want: https://developer.nvidia.com/content/cuda-example-introduction-general-purpose-gpu-programming-0

I know it is a very specific problem and it takes a lot of effort to read it but any suggestion is welcome.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just figured out how to make it work... so i basically changed the dimensions of the window from 1024 to 512:

*ripple.cu*: `#define DIM 1024` ----> `#define DIM 512`

I don't know why but it works now! I just got lucky.